# Unable to define a set raphaelJS

Tags: javascript, raphael

So I tried to define a set in raphael js but it keeps giving me syntax errors in the raphael.js file (line 3744). I realize that this is probably a bracket that hasn't been closed within the function that im trying to write, but for the life of me I can't seem to find it.

```
var drawsymbol = function(paper, x, y, symboltype){
var st = paper.set(), newx = x+50;
if(symboltype==1){

    st.push(
        var circ = paper.cicle(x,y,50);//.attr({fill: "rgb(255,0,0)", stroke: "none", opacity: 1});
        var conPoint1 = paper.circle(newx, y, 5);//.attr({fill: "rgb(255, 0,0)", stroke: "none", opacity: .5});
        pathString = 'M'+newx+' '+y+ 'l10 0';
        var path = paper.path(pathString);
    );

}

return symbolset;
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the push method incorrectly on the set, you cannot terminate each line with `;` like you are, they need to be comma delimited objects as per the docs:

```
var st = paper.set();
st.push(
    paper.circle(10, 10, 5),
    paper.circle(30, 10, 5)
);
st.attr({fill: "red"}); // changes the fill of both circles
```

Decide what you want adding to the set in the push method and it will be fine.

Comment: As a followup, can I declare variables inside the push method? or should i declare them before hand and just push them on?

Comment: No the push method expects raphael elements only. You should treat it like you would an array!